# Instantaneous acceleration in non uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

How is instantaneous acceleration different from tangential acceleration in a non uniform circular motion?

We know that instantaneous acceleration is tangent to a point at any given time and so is the tangential acceleration. What is there difference?

Comment: in constant circular motion, you only have a _radial_ component of acceleration - always moving towards the center, never getting there. _Tangential_ acceleration is _along the tangent_ so at right angles to the radial vector. These are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: @Floris I was asking the difference between tangential and instantaneous acceleration in a circular motion(non uniform). Not between radial and tangential acceleration.

Comment: Instantaneous acceleration is the vector sum of tangential acceleration and radial acceleration (at a certain time).

Comment: Why would instantaneous acceleration be tangent?  Instantaneous should be the value of acceleration at any one point in time (distinct from average acceleration).  The time derivative of velocity evaluated at one point in time would be the instantaneous acceleration.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Can you then tell me the direction of instantaneous acceleration in non uniform circular motion?

Comment: There is no single direction.  If the object is speeding up, it will be a vector somewhere between ahead and to the center.  If it is slowing down, it will be somewhere between to the center and to the rear.  Since the motion is circular, some component will point to the center.

Comment: Doesn't *instantaneous acceleration* just mean *acceleration* as opposed to *average acceleration*? Are you actually asking how the radial acceleration differs from the tangential acceleration? If so I can't see what would be meant by a difference. Perhaps you could clarify your question to indicate what difference you have in mind.